# Type Erasure with dart LinkedList?

Tags: dart

This is the program:

```
import 'dart:collection';

class MyLinkedListEntry<T> extends LinkedListEntry<MyLinkedListEntry> {
  T value;
  MyLinkedListEntry(T this.value);
  @override
  String toString() => '${super.toString()}: ${value}';
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  var l = LinkedList<MyLinkedListEntry>();

  var s = MyLinkedListEntry("SomeString");
  var p = MyLinkedListEntry(125);

  l.add(s);
  s.insertAfter(p);
  p.insertAfter(MyLinkedListEntry(126));

  l.forEach((e) => print(e));
}
```

And it gives this output:

```
Instance of 'MyLinkedListEntry<String>': SomeString
Instance of 'MyLinkedListEntry<int>': 125
Instance of 'MyLinkedListEntry<dynamic>': 126
```

I expected the third instance to be of type `LinkedList<int>` as well. Why it's not?

This is with Dart 2.13.4.

Comment: Correction: LinkedList<int> should read MyLinkedListEntry<int>.

Answer (score 2):

### 0. `dynamic` in type checking

Everything is a subclass of `dynamic`:

```dart
print(1 is dynamic);    // Outputs true
print("a" is dynamic);  // Outputs true
```

In fact, Dart even shows a warning when using the above code: *Unnecessary type check; the result is always 'true'*.

### 1. Omiting type parameters in declarations

In the declaration

```dart
class MyLinkedListEntry<T> extends LinkedListEntry<MyLinkedListEntry>
```

note that you're not passing the type parameter of `MyLinkedListEntry` in the type parameter of `LinkedListEntry`. From [docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-problems) (emphasis mine):

> When a generic class is instantiated without explicit type arguments, each type parameter defaults to its type bound [...] if one is explicitly given, **or `dynamic` otherwise**.

So Dart interprets this as

```dart
class MyLinkedListEntry<T> extends LinkedListEntry<MyLinkedListEntry<dynamic>>
```

### 2. The `extends` clause in type parameters

Let's look at the [declaration of `LinkedListEntry`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/065872e802209ffa97aa3fad204758830b6100a0/sdk/lib/collection/linked_list.dart#L223):

```dart
abstract class LinkedListEntry<E extends LinkedListEntry<E>>
```

Note that `LinkedListEntry` requires a type parameter named `E`, which must be a subclass of `LinkedListEntry`. When you use `LinkedListEntry<E>`, `E` must extend `LinkedListEntry<E>`.

When you declare `MyLinkedListEntry<T>`, **you're passing `MyLinkedListEntry<dynamic>` as `E`**. Since `T` always extends from `dynamic`, `MyLinkedListEntry<T>` extends `LinkedListEntry<MyLinkedListEntry<dynamic>>`, so this is a valid declaration.

### 3. Type parameters in methods

In the expression

```
p.insertAfter(MyLinkedListEntry(126));
```

you're using the `insertAfter` method declared in the `LinkedListEntry` class. Let's look at [its declaration](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/065872e802209ffa97aa3fad204758830b6100a0/sdk/lib/collection/linked_list.dart#L262):

```dart
void insertAfter(E entry)
```

Since `E` is equal to `MyLinkedListEntry<dynamic>`, Dart will interpret any `MyLinkedListEntry` call to this method as

```dart
void insertAfter(MyLinkedListEntry<dynamic> entry)
```

Therefore, when you do

```dart
p.insertAfter(MyLinkedListEntry(126));
```

you're actually passing an upcasted `MyLinkedListEntry<dynamic>`, which explains the output.

### The solution

Explicitly pass the type parameter of `MyLinkedListEntry` when inserting:

```dart
p.insertAfter(MyLinkedListEntry<int>(126));
```

Comment: Thank you for your elaborated response. So I understand that 3 causes the "type erasure". And I found that the runtime type of the value field of the List entries isn't erased, i.e. changing print(entry) to print(entry.value.runtimeType.toString()) gives String, int, int as output. Which is good.

Comment: But I found that adding `l.last.value = null` to my example it compiles and runs without runtime error. Doing `l.first.value = null`instead does compile but produces a runtime error. I found while working with json conversion that dynamic can be misused to assign null to non-nullable value. That should not be I guess. Is there a need for introducing something like `dynamic?` to separate nullable from non-nullable items of type `dynamic`?